# CSS Polyfill to make "page-break-after: avoid" and "target-counter" work?

Tags: css, printing, puppeteer

Does anyone know of a css polyfill that makes it possible to make use of `page-break-after: avoid` and target-counter, for example like this:

```
.myDiv a::after {
  content: leader(".") target-counter(attr(href), page, decimal)
}
```

The leader is not absolutely necessary (but would be nice).

The use case for `the page-break-after: avoid` is that I want to avoid ever breaking a page right after a heading, and make sure at least the first paragraph (which for the record has `page-break-inside: avoid`) gets on the same page as the heading.

I want to use the target-counter so that I am able to generate table of contents for my PDFs using puppeteer. (I saw [Paged.JS](https://www.pagedmedia.org/paged-js/) use this in their example, and they had it working, so I'm guessing they created some sort of a polyfill themselves)

Comment: I work on Paged.js so i can help a bit here. Paged.js is a polyfill that lets you do what you need here (leaders are not there yet, but we have options for that). a couple of infos: - page-break-inside is behind deprecated for break-inside (as it can work for columns and pages) - target-counter is not yet supported by any browser, polyfill is the only option right now (and im not sure that’s gonna be supported soon). But Paged.js is able to handle those
- support for leader() is even worse, and we use complex html and css tricks to make those in our layout using Paged.js we have a new site: ww

Comment: @julientaq Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure how paged.js is supposed to work, but this is what I've tried:  
-I link to the paged.js script in my php view.  
-My markup looks like this:  
    `<span className="pageNumber">
        <a href={chapterid is here}>Page</a>
    </span>`  
-My css looks like this:  
`.pageNumber { 
    float: right;
    a::after {
        content: target-counter(attr(href), page, decimal);
     }
 }`  
But this doesn't seem to do anything. I try to go to the page and save as PDF as well, still doesn't work. Any pointers?

Comment: Basically all I need is the polyfill, and not the entire book-writing framework. Is there a way to get just that?